# Ruby on Rails - Keep getting a error when trying to run "rake db:migrate"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, dbmigrate

I'm new to learning Ruby on Rails and when I run "rake db:migrate" in the command line I receive the following error:

> rake aborted!
> SyntaxError: >/Users/user_name/Sites/simple_cms/db/migrate/20140423221836_alter_users.rb:15: syntax >error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
> ...dmin_users", "email", :string :default => "", :null => false)
> ...                               ^
>
> Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
> (See full trace by running task with --trace)**

Here is my code:

```
class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def up
    rename_table("users", "admin_users")
    add_column("admin_users", "username", :string, :limit => 25, :after => "email")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string, :limit => 100)
    rename_column("admin_users", "password", "hashed_password")
    puts "*** Adding an index is next ***"
    add_index("admin_users", "username")
  end

  def down
    remove_index("admin_users", "username")
    rename_column("admin_users", "hashed_password", "password")
    change_column("admin_users", "email", :string :default => "", :null => false)
    remove_column("admin_users", "username")
    rename_table("admin_users", "users")
  end

end
```

I keep checking and rechecking my code but can't find the solution... Can someone with better eyes than me take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 3rd line of `down` method, you missed a *comma*

```
change_column("admin_users", "email", :string :default => "", :null => false)

                                             ^ 
                                           ## missing comma
```

which is why you are getting error as `unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...dmin_users", "email", :string :default => "", :null => false)`

Simply, add a *comma* between `:string` and `:default` and run `rake db:migrate`.